# Correct way to "extrude inward" (intrude?)

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, extrude

I have this mesh:

[image]

I want it to become like:

[image]

But if I simply extrude inward, it becomes:

[image]

I know in this simplified case I could just extrude the square in the center and scale them downwards. But I'd like to know if there a "correct" way to do the opposite of extrusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Extrude Manifold

In your last image, the infinitely thin areas created around the edge are called non-manifold. Blender now has a tool called *Extrude Manifold* which will automatically fix this issue.

To use this tool, press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> for the extrude menu and select it.

[image: 1]

Upon dragging your cursor down, you will see the satisfying result:

[image: 2]

Comment: day successful. Learnt again something from you! ;) +1

Comment: I almost forgot about this tool when I was about to start answering. Watching Blender Today live streams paid off. 

Comment: I didn't expect there is a tool for this *exact* reason. Many thanks!

Comment: ... Implemented because everyone was getting SketchUp-envy :)

Comment: @LaiYu-Hsuan The only thing you have to be aware of: you have this edge loop below the top. If you _Extrude Manifold_ past this loop, it will look the same like your normal extrude, the border faces will stay like a "wall" around the inner extrude. Or, if you do that but then move the faces back above that edge loop with G > Z, and then try to _Extrude Manifold_ again, it will cause some weird behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

Select these faces, then press <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>Z</kbd> and move down.

Then select middle face and extrude up.

[image: Select the middle face.]